# Calling JavaScript function from code behind after Response.End()

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, httpresponse

In my `.aspx` page, I have a `div` that I need to hide using JavaScript after an attachment is downloaded. I used the below code to get it done. But since `Response` is coming into the scenes, the `HideDiv()` does not get fired.

I even tried making the div a server control and setting visibility to `false`. I also tried putting the `ClientScript` part after the `Response.End();` and inside the `finally` block.

```
    try{

    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Hide", "HideDiv()", true);
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
    Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename + "");
    Response.Write(tw.ToString());
    Response.End();
}
catch (System.Threading.ThreadAbortException)
        {

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //log error
        }
        finally
        {

        }
```

Any idea to get the JavaScript to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create `.ashx` Generic Handler To Download File then You can Call it something like this

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Hide", "HideDiv()", true);
Response.Redirect("MyHandler.ashx")
```

OR

js function to hide div and Redirect

```
function HideDivNRedirect()
{
  //hide div
window.location.href='myhandler.ashx';
}

ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Hide", "HideDivNRedirect();", true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Calling javascript function from code behind will not work after `Response.End();` But can use `beforeunload`, it will fire after `response.End();`

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function() {
    // here your function
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call the function from code behind like this :

Form.aspx.cs

If you want to call on `button click`.

```
protected void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Hide", "HideDiv();", true);
}
```